# wget .listing file, is there a way to specify the name of it

Tags: linux, wget

Ok so I need to run wget but I'm prohibited from creating 'dot' files in the location that I need to run the wget. So my question is 'Can I get wget to use a name other than .listing that I can specify'.

further clarification : this is to sync / mirror an ftp folder with a local one, So using the -O option is not really useful, as I require all files to maintain format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-O` option to set the output filename, as in:

```
wget -O file http://stackoverflow.com
```

You can also use `wget --help` to get a complete list of options.

---

For folks that come along afterwards, and are surprised by an answer to the wrong question, here is a copy of one of the comments below:

> @FelixD, yes, unfortunately misunderstood the question. **Looking at the code for wget version 1.19 (Feb 2017), specifically ftp.c, it appears that the .listing file is hardcoded in macro `LIST_FILENAME`, and no override possible**. There are probably better options for mirroring ftp sites - maybe take a look at lftp and its mirror command, also includes parallel downloads: [lftp.yar.ru](http://lftp.yar.ru)

Comment: The poster is not asking regarding the output file name, but the name of the temporary `.listing` file wget creates e.g. when downloading with globbing from FTP. When using more than one instance of wget on the same directory, these files collide. Not sure why this is marked as the answer, as it isn't.

Comment: @FelixD, yes, unfortunately misunderstood the question.  Looking at the code for wget version 1.19 (Feb 2017), specifically ftp.c, it appears that the `.listing` file is hardcoded in macro `LIST_FILENAME`, and no override possible.  There are probably better options for mirroring ftp sites - maybe take a look at lftp and its mirror command, also includes parallel downloads: https://lftp.yar.ru

Comment: thanks for your fast reply and checking the source code, pity it's hardcoded. Will have a look at lftp tomorrow, may also have another workaround for my specific task.

Answer (score 0):

@Paul: You can use that -O option specified by spong

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't do this.

wget/src/ftp.c

```
/* File where the "ls -al" listing will be saved.  */
#ifdef MSDOS
#define LIST_FILENAME "_listing"
#else
#define LIST_FILENAME ".listing"
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem; 
wget seems to save the `.listing` file in current directory where wget was called from, regardless of `-O path/outpout_file`

As an ugly/desperate solution we can try to run wget from random directories:

`cd /temp/random_1; wget ftp://example.com/ -O /full/save_path/to_file_1.txt`

`cd /temp/random_2; wget ftp://example.com/ -O /full/save_path/to_file_2.txt`

Note: manual says that using the `--no-remove-listing` option will cause it to create `.listing.1`, .`listing.2`, etc, so that might be an option to avoid conflicts.

Note: .listing file is not created at all if ftp login failed.