# How to overwrite ".listing" file when using "wget" command

Tags: linux, wget

I have a generic script that uses wget to download the file (passed as parameter to the script) from FTP server. The script always downloads the files into the same local folder. The problem I am running into is that `.listing` file created by `wget` gets deleted by default so if the script is called in parallel for different files, whichever process gets to delete the `.listing` file succeeds and the rest fail.
So I tried to use `--no-remove-listing` along with `wget` command, but then I get the error:
`File ".listing" already there; not retrieving.`
I looked at another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588285/wget-listing-file-is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-name-of-it) but as mentioned in the comments by original poster, the question hasn't been answered even though it is marked so.

One option I was thinking about is to change the script to create subdirectory with filename and download the file there. But since it is a large script, I was trying to see if there is an easier option to just change `wget` command.